# How to get all possible combinations of array elements without duplicate

Tags: matlab, combinations, unique

I have a vector of string elements `vector = {'A','B','C'}`.
I want to generate all possible combination of the three elements of the array but without duplicate.
I expect the following result: `{'A', 'B', 'C', 'AB', 'AC', 'BC', 'ABC'}`.
How can I do that in MATLAB?

Comment: Thank you but No, it's not. the exaple that you gave me search for the combination of the elements of two vectors. Forme am loking to find all the combiantion that ca be based on the elments of the same array.

Comment: @Wolfie, thank you so much It was very helpful, I just forgot to mention 'ABC'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your desired result, you want all the combinations with 2 choices of `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, and `''` (nothing). You can do it with [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) as follows

```
result = nchoosek(' ABC', 2) % note space for empty
```

Output

```
result =
  6×2 char array
    ' A'
    ' B'
    ' C'
    'AB'
    'AC'
    'BC'
```

Then removing the spaces and converting the combinations to a cell array:

```
result = strrep(cellstr(result), ' ', '')
```

---

As Wolfie pointed out, this only works for single character input, for multi character inputs we can use string arrays instead of char arrays:

```
result = nchoosek(["","A1","B2","C3"], 2);
result = result(:,1) +  result(:,2) % string cat
% result = cellstr(result); % optional if want cell output
```

```
result = 
  6×1 string array
    "A1"
    "B2"
    "C3"
    "A1B2"
    "A1C3"
    "B2C3"
```

Comment: worth noting that this only works for single-character values, if the OP was only showing us a "toy example" where their real input was a cell array, there will likely be an additional step or two using this to create an indexing array first...

Comment: @Wolfie oh indeed, but luckily we can work around that with string arrays :)

Comment: Nice, I always feel like a dinosaur when I remember string arrays exist and are very performant for things like this